# Kafka consumer offset commit issue

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-kafka, project-reactor

For Spring WebFlux which uses Reactor Kafka, I have following code for my consumer:

```
public EventConsumer(KafkaReceiver<String, String> inputEventReceiver,
                     MessageHelper messageHelper,
                     List<EventProcessor> eventProcessors) {
    this.inputEventReceiver = inputEventReceiver;
    this.messageHelper = messageHelper;
    this.eventProcessorChain = new EventProcessorChain(eventProcessors);
}

public Disposable consumeMessage() {
    return processRecord()
            .onBackpressureBuffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
            .limitRate(MAX_BATCH_SIZE)
            .retryWhen(Retry.indefinitely())
            .subscribe(record -> {}, error -> log.error("error while consuming event with message {}", error.getMessage()));
}

public Flux<EventWrapper> processRecord() {
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> receiverRecord = Flux.defer(inputEventReceiver::receive);
    return receiverRecord.flatMap(this::processMessage);
}

private Flux<EventWrapper> processMessage(final ReceiverRecord<String, String> receiverRecord) {
    EventWrapper eventWrapper = messageHelper.fetchDataFromRecord(receiverRecord);
    return processEventThroughChain(eventWrapper, receiverRecord);
}

private Flux<EventWrapper> processEventThroughChain(EventWrapper eventWrapper, ReceiverRecord<String, String> receiverRecord) {
    return eventProcessorChain.processEvent(eventWrapper)
            .filter(EventWrapper::isValid)
            .doOnNext(result -> receiverRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge()).flux();
}
```

The value of `MAX_BATCH_SIZE` I have kept as 500. The problem is when the consumption is started for this consumer, if an event fails (in my case isValid is false), I am not committing its offset as I want the event to be retried.

But what happens is that in the batch of event, if an event in the middle fails and does not get committed, it's still not retried as events after this in the same batch get committed.

The only solution I can think of is having a retry logic, but that I have to keep on retrying if I don't want the event to be missed. This will take up one of my consumer. If I continue consuming event after retry, this event will be lost, so that is why I am retrying indefinitely for the time being, and need manual intervention currently for the issue.

So, is there any way where I can handle this in WebFlux. The solution which seems correct to me is having a DLQ (dead-letter queue), but apart from that is it possible to handle it in Reactor side?

Answer (score 0):

It is not retried because you need to wrap your method in a `Flux.defer(() -> processRecord())...` or `fromSuplier`. You can have a look at this article for more details: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/project-reactor-using-retry-and-retrywhen-examples

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but the issue is not about the retry method. Its about the event in middle which did not commit not getting retried by kafka broker because in that batch the events after that got committed.